# Match file names in a directory to Pandas series, delete non matching files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm on Python 2.7.

I have a bunch of files (basically outlook emails) in a directory. Sample file names:

```
RE: We have Apple.msg
RE: Orange are in stock.msg
RE: Pick up some cabbage please.msg
```

I have a pandas series

```
Granny Smith Apple
High Quality Orange
Delicious soup
```

How can I loop through the directory, find file names that contain words in the pandas series, and delete the files which find no matches? In the above example, `RE: Pick up some cabbage please.msg` would be deleted, as `Apple` and `Orange` were found in the Pandas series.

Edit: I would like to actually delete the files in the directory that find no matches

Answer (score 1):

We can using `str.contains`

```
s1[pd.Series(l).str.contains('|'.join(s.str.split().sum()))]
Out[560]: 
0          RE: We have Apple.msg
1    RE: Orange are in stock.msg
dtype: object
```

---

Data input

---

```
l=['RE: We have Apple.msg',
'RE: Orange are in stock.msg',
'RE: Pick up some cabbage please.msg']
s1=pd.Series(l)
s=pd.Series(['Granny Smith Apple','High Quality Orange','Delicious soup'])
```

Comment: Is it possible to loop through the directory, and delete the files with no matches?

Comment: You can not read them , I will not recommend directly delete the original data  , you can filter out the name them , rewrite them into a new folder , since apply any change to the original data is very dangerous, since it will loss the original data .@JamesSoh

Answer (score 1):

Can use `os` and `listdir`, then `str.contains`

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
m = '/' # your path
files_in_directory = [f for f in listdir(m) if isfile(join(m, f))]
files = pd.Series(files_in_directory)

s = pd.Series(["Granny Smith Apple",
"High Quality Orange",
"Delicious soup"])

z = pd.Series(s.str.split().sum())
files.str.contains('|'.join(z))
```

Comment: Is it possible to loop through the directory, and delete / read / do stuff with the files that do not match?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution i found that works for me

```
#contains strings we want to filter
checklist = [x.lower() for x in checklist]

m = r''  # path where our files are contained
new_directory = r'' # path where we will move the matched files to to


for each_checklist in checklist:
    print 'now checking for keyword ' + str(each_checklist)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(m):
        for i in files:
            if each_checklist in i.lower():
                # this moves the file from root, to target directory
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, i), os.path.join(new_directory, i))
            else:
                None
```